# Unable to run in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For some reason I do not have any ability to run the below code in IntelliJ. Neither the Run button or any key shortcuts will work.

I'm relatively new to this but I believe the below code should work, I have declared the public Elevator class and variables in another class file in the project.

```
public static void main(String args []){
    Elevator myElevator = new Elevator();

    myElevator.openDoor();
    myElevator.closeDoor();
    myElevator.goDown();
    myElevator.goUp();
    myElevator.goUp();
    myElevator.goUp();
}
```

Ive even had a colleague look at this and he's stumped. Is this simply some issue with the way my project is set up?

Apologies if I'm just being thick and can't see it.

Comment: what error do you get? "doesn't run" isn't a very clear description

Comment: Did you run as a Java Application ?

Comment: I'm not recieving any error, its simply I can't work out *how* to run it. All of my classes worked up until about mid day yesterday, and now I can't run any of them.

Comment: without getting any form of error? so how do you know they don't run? how did you try to run? what changed in your configuration?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the IDE screen?

Comment: I _guess_ it is caused by a sudden error of Java configuration inside IDEA. However, without any error information, no one can answer your question, like Stultuske said.

Comment: @TPulford Did you check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html ? What happens when you start the Application configuration configured for this class?